# How to execute curl along with python in bash?

Tags: python, bash, shell, curl

I have a shell script in which i get a jsonresponse. I am using python to parse the json , and inside each json object i want to fetch id and again submit a curl request for each application Id from a shell script.

Currently am doing it like this , which am unable to do it successfully due to syntax errors. Can you please help me out

Any suggestions are helpful thank you.

```
curl -v -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" 'http://host/ws/v1/cluster/apps?state=PENDING' |
    python3 -c "import sys, json; jsonObject = json.load(sys.stdin)['apps']; for row in jsonObject['app']: print(row['id'])"
```

Output:

**{"apps":{"app":[{"id":1},{"id":2}]}}**

Comment: Add output of curl, and how do you want to use those *ids* to your question.

Comment: Why not do everything in Python, using the `requests` module?

Comment: Or use `jq` to parse the returned value in `bash`.

Comment: Why are you sending the `Content-type` header in a `GET` request? They have no contents.

Comment: @Barmar content-type not required as you mentioned . I have a requirement to do it in bash itself, can't allow the control flow outside of bash

Comment: @oguzismail Added output section , i want to extract the id's (values) and do another curl on each id .

Comment: @Barmar: "[GET requests] have no contents." [Not correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body). They *shouldn't*, but can, and sometimes do.

Comment: `curl -sS ... | jq -r '.apps.app[].id'` extracts all ids, you can assign them to bash variables and use for other requests. but it might not be necessary, a curl config can be created using jq and directly piped to `curl -sSK-`.

Comment: @Amadan "it is never useful to do so." Since it has no semantic meaning, specifying the type is also unnecessary.

Comment: @Barmar: 1) Read the rest of that answer, in particular the update that says with the updated RFC, the restriction that GET body "SHOULD be ignored" semantics is gone, replaced with a weaker claim that GET body does not have a defined semantics by the RFC, but is not prohibited. 2) SHOULD is not MUST, it is allowed to be broken; 3) Read the comments about Elasticsearch on the same page; whether you think it's a good idea or not (I think not, FTR), people are actually doing it, and if you need to interact with such a product you may be forced to, so "never useful" is disingenuous.

Comment: @Barmar: Trying to get back to topic, `Content-Type` is truly unnecessary _here_, since _this_ request has no body.